# Magisk Hide bypassed my root detection implemented for my Android App

Tags: android, root

I have implemented root detection code for my current native android application. But recently Using Magisk Hide , the root mechanism was bypassed. I have used the below code for root detection in my side :

```
public class RootUtil {
    public static boolean isDeviceRooted() {
        return checkRootMethod1() || checkRootMethod2() || checkRootMethod3();
    }

    private static boolean checkRootMethod1() {
        String buildTags = android.os.Build.TAGS;
        return buildTags != null && buildTags.contains("test-keys");
    }

    private static boolean checkRootMethod2() {
        String[] paths = { "/system/app/Superuser.apk", "/sbin/su", "/system/bin/su", "/system/xbin/su", "/data/local/xbin/su", "/data/local/bin/su", "/system/sd/xbin/su",
                "/system/bin/failsafe/su", "/data/local/su", "/su/bin/su"};
        for (String path : paths) {
            if (new File(path).exists()) return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

    private static boolean checkRootMethod3() {
        Process process = null;
        try {
            process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(new String[] { "/system/xbin/which", "su" });
            BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(process.getInputStream()));
            if (in.readLine() != null) return true;
            return false;
        } catch (Throwable t) {
            return false;
        } finally {
            if (process != null) process.destroy();
        }
    }
}
```

How can we solve during this case??

Comment: Check out [rootbeer library](https://github.com/scottyab/rootbeer) and the [Play Integrity API](https://developer.android.com/google/play/integrity) (which replaces the SafetyNet API).

Comment: @vinayak why restrict your app from being detected? Please note apps are by default not installed with Magiskhide enabled. This is different from detecting if there s an exploit, you will only attract frustration from your users.

Comment: @AlexanderHoffmann -  It was working perfecting after using rootbeer library.